# Set background fill, stroke, and opacity of HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I use the below code to set styles of `myCanvas`, but I am not able to set `fillStyle`. Yet, `strokeStyle` and `lineWidth` is working fine. Could anyone please help with this?

```
Init()
{
     var can = byId('myCanvas');

        // get it's context
        hdc = can.getContext('2d');

        hdc.strokeStyle = 'red';
        hdc.lineWidth = 2;

        // Fill the path
        hdc.fillStyle = "#9ea7b8";
        hdc.opacity = 0.2;
        hdc.fill();
}

// And call the drawPoly function with coordinates.
function drawPoly(coOrdStr) {
        var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
        hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
        var i, n;
        n = mCoords.length;
        hdc.beginPath();
        hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
        for (i = 2; i < n; i += 2) {
            hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i + 1]);
        }
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
        hdc.stroke();

    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Init()
{
    var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    h = parseInt(document.getElementById("myCanvas").getAttribute("height"));
    w=parseInt(document.getElementById("myCanvas").getAttribute("width"));

    // get it's context
    hdc = can.getContext('2d');

    hdc.strokeStyle = 'red';
    hdc.lineWidth = 2;

    // Fill the path
    hdc.fillStyle = "#9ea7b8";
    hdc.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    can.style.opacity = '0.2';
}
```

Be careful that `style.height` or `style.width` will not work with canvas.

Answer (score 18):

**Style / CSS:**

```
<style>#myCanvas { background-color: rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2); }</style>
```

---

**jQuery:**

```
$('#myCanvas').css('background-color', 'rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2)');
```

---

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2)';
```

Comment: Why using jQuery to add CSS?

Comment: Because when working with canvas it's usually a benefit to be able to change the appearance with code. You are correct though, it's fully possible to do the same with plain css.

Comment: This is a better solution than `fillRect`

Comment: This is not a better solution than fillRect in every case. BECAUSE:

If you set this canvas as div background, canvas will not have background if you are using <canvas style=" THIS THING "></canvas>

Canvas (which is set as background for a div) WILL have background, if you will use fillRect instead.

In other cases jquery is much shorter solution than fillRect.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `style.height` and `style.width` do work with canvas, you can also set those to a different size without changing the inner resolution, e.g. running a 400x300 game in a fullscreen 1024x768 canvas.

Comment: If using canvas style properties instead of canvas element properties be sure you change the width & height proportionally or else any drawings on the canvas will be horizontally or vertically distorted. ;-)

Comment: Well, sometimes that's exactly what you want, though. :)