# Angular: How to set the background color of canvas while generating image?

Tags: html5-canvas

I have tried to download canvas as an image, but it is downloading with transparent background. How do I set the background color to an image?

**This is the code I've tried:**

```
 this.canvas = document.getElementById('barchart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        var download = document.getElementById("download");
        let url = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png","image/octet-stream");
        download.setAttribute("href", url);
```

Comment: Sadly, `background-color` is a DOM attribute and so when you are transferring the image that information is lost. One way would be to just do a fill stroke as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488590/set-background-fill-stroke-and-opacity-of-html5-canvas#20488706 (where the fill color can be taken from the DOM element's background-color attribute).

Comment: You could use drawImage() (javascript) to combine image a onto a white canvas and create a new image?